# Check if the input is wrong

Tags: javascript

I am asking to input a letter. Then I should check if the letter is one of the letters in the prelist and then it is supposed to display some words

!== is not working for the letters

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Type H/B/U:</p>

<input id="tipping" value="H" type="text"/>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var b,r4;
  b= document.getElementById("tipping").value;
 if (b !=="H"||b !=="U" ||b !=="B") {
   r4="Du har ikke brukt stort bokstav eller tastet ugyldig tegn";
 } else if (b==="H"){
   r4="Hjemme";
 } else if (b==="U"){
   r4="Uavgjort";
 } else if(b==="B") {
   r4="Borte";
 }
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = r4;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

One is supposed to only type B,H,U. If B is typed then the message Borte is displayed and so on.. .

Comment: Read it out loud `if variable b is not the string H` Well when you type "B" it is not H so it is true....

Comment: You probably wanted an `and` condition in the first statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong. In order for it to not go into that first if statement, B would need to be three values. Since a variable can not be three things it fails. Your logic should be using an AND, not an OR.

But that logic still does not make sense. You should just have that be the else.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var b, r4;
  b = document.getElementById("tipping").value.toUpperCase();
  if (b === "H") {
    r4 = "Hjemme";
  } else if (b === "U") {
    r4 = "Uavgjort";
  } else if (b === "B") {
    r4 = "Borte";
  } else {
    r4 = "Du har ikke brukt stort bokstav eller tastet ugyldig tegn";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = r4;
}
```

```html
<input id="tipping" value="H" type="text" />

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

this works

you also want to make sure it works if user types lowercase h,u,b

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Type H/B/U:</p>

<input id="tipping" value="H" type="text"/>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var b,r4;
  b= document.getElementById("tipping").value;

  if(b === "B" || b === "b"){
    r4="Borte";
  } else if( b === "U" || b === "u"){
    r4="Uavgjort";
  } else if( b  === "H" || b  === "h"){
    r4="Hjemme";
  } else {
    r4="Du har ikke brukt stort bokstav eller tastet ugyldig tegn";
  }
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = r4;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

or use modern if else

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Type H/B/U:</p>

<input id="tipping" value="H" type="text"/>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var b,r4;
  b= document.getElementById("tipping").value;

  b === "H" || b === "h" ? r4 = "Hjemme" :
  b === "U" || b === "u" ? r4 = "Uavgjort" :
  b === "B" || b === "b" ? r4 = "Borte" :
  r4 = "Du har ikke brukt stort bokstav eller tastet ugyldig tegn" 


   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = r4;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `switch()` would be much more appropriate here. If the input doesn't match "H", "U", or "B" display the default text.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        b = document.getElementById("tipping").value;
        switch (b) {
          case "H":
            r4 = "Hjemme";
            break;
          case "U":
            r4 = "Uavgjort";
            break;
          case "B":
            r4 = "Borte";
            break;
          default:
            r4 = "Du har ikke brukt stort bokstav eller tastet ugyldig tegn";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = r4;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Type H/B/U:</p>
    <input id="tipping" value="H" type="text" />
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```